# UseDefault Create the issue in the tableView method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I just create the Bus ticket booking app. Now i want to save the search history (City Name and Date) and Display in my tableView. So this is what i coding in my `SearchButtonAction`.

```
@IBAction func btnSearchAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if txtTo.text != nil && txtFrom.text != nil {
        arrTo.append(txtTo.text!)
        arrFrom.append(txtTo.text!)

        UserDefault.set(arrTo, forKey: "arrTo")
        UserDefault.set(arrFrom,forKey: "arrFrom")...
    }
}
```

Now on my `historyViewController` I just coding like below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrFrom.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell") as! RecentCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.lblFrom.text = arrFrom[indexPath.row]
    cell.lblTo.text = arrTo[indexPath.row]
    tblSearch.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

So it's Call only `numberOfRowsInSection` Method again and again Even arr count is more than one. What is the correct way to save two textField text in UserDefaults.

Comment: remove `tblSearch.reloadData()` from `cellForRowAt `.

Answer (score 0):

Remove reloading datas of `tblSearch` from `cellForRowAt` TableView data source method

Answer (score 0):

When you reload `tableview` inside `cellForRowAt` method, `tableview` will go into looping. So you `tableview` won't display. So please remove `tblSearch.reloadData()` this line from `cellForRow` methhod.
please check screenshot, so you will get the better idea about looping.
http://prntscr.com/lte2mo